# Can Gulp be used for converting images to next-gen formats?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using Gulp 3 and I want to convert all of my images using one Gulp task. It is proving hard to do so, since there is no package that can do that.

I am using gulp-imagemin for optimizing images and I found the gulp-webp for converting the images to webp format. I couldn't find any available packages that can convert them in JPEG 2000 or JPEG XR.

```
 gulp.task('images', function () {
     return gulp.src('./public/images/**/*')
         .pipe(imagemin({ progressive: true}))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/images-nextgen/'))
         .pipe(webp())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/images-nextgen/'))
});
```

I got the results I wanted, namely it optimized my images and converted all of them to webp. 
Can you tell me how I can achieve the same for JPEG 2000 and JPEG XR since I don't want to use online converters all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made gulp plugins for converting images to JPEG 2000 and JPEG XR using ImageMagick and nConvert respectively: [gulp-jpeg-2000](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jpeg-2000) and [gulp-jpeg-xr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jpeg-xr).